# How to solve file download path error in VBScript ?

Tags: vbscript

I am running the following VBScript program, `download.vbs`

```
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "http://websitelink/textfile.txt", False
xHttp.Send

with bStrm
.type = 1 '//binary
.open
.write xHttp.responseBody
.savetofile "c:\dump.txt", 2 '//overwrite
end with
```

in this program, it will download the textfile from given web url and save it to local disk in the given path.

but the problem is, its working well when i change the download path to local disk `d:`

and showing the following error when i use local disk `c:` as download path.

VBScript error message,

```
Script:     C:\test\download.vbs
Line:       10
Char:       5
Error:      Write to file failed.
Code:       800A0BBC
Source:     ADODB.Stream
```

Please help. i will be very thankfull.

Comment: You must have administrator privileges to copy to OS drive!

Comment: [Try to run the script elevated](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+vbs+elevated).

Answer (score 0):

If the file doesn't exist - you want to use 1 on the safetofile. You can add some code

```
Const AdTypeBinary = 1, AdTypeText = 2
Const FsoRead = 1, FsoWrite = 2, FsoAppend = 8
Const BstrmCreate = 1, BstrmOvrWrt = 2
dim FSO: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "http://websitelink/textfile.txt", False
xHttp.Send
mysavefile = "D:\dump.txt" 'Set your save-file here 



with bStrm
    .type = AdTypeBinary ' YOU MAY WANT TO CHANGE FILE TYPE FOR TEXT/BINARY
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody

    if ( FSO.FileExists( mysavefile ) ) then
        .savetofile mysavefile, BstrmCreate
    else
        .savetofile mysavefile, BstrmOvrWrt
    end if
end with
```